# Does WooCommerce send webhook calls if the order status is updated by a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

Will WooCommerce propagate the order status change?

I have a POS plugin installed, and I also registered a webhook url to receive order updates.

Normal order updates via WC admin or store front works, but if the POS plugin updates the order status, WC does not fire order update notification to my URL, is this expect behavior or I missed some configuration?

Comment: Yes only if the plugin uses the `WC_Order` method `update_status()` to change order status, instead of something else… Also the webhook should be related to one of the 3 hooks that are triggered by [`status_transition()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/class-wc-order.php#L363-L373)

Comment: Thanks, how do I mark this as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes only if the plugin uses the `WC_Order` method [`update_status()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/class-wc-order.php#L317-L350) to change order status, instead of something else…

Also the webhook should be related to one of the [3 action hooks that are triggered by `status_transition()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/class-wc-order.php#L363-L373):

- `woocommerce_order_status_$STATUS_TRANSITION[from]_to_$STATUS_TRANSITION[to]`
- `woocommerce_order_status_$STATUS_TRANSITION[to]`
- `woocommerce_order_status_changed`